# Dows laravel “use” the Controller class? StyleCI thinks not

Tags: php, laravel, coding-style

Just started using [StyleCI](https://styleci.io) with my laravel project. The start of an example simple controller that I wrote may look like:

```
<?php

namepsace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class FooController extends Controller
{
    ...
```

StyleCI is telling me the `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller` is unused. Which may be the case, I may have misundertsood this.

Could someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: Oh, it's used. You'd get a fatal error if you didn't `use` it.

Comment: @Andrew I’ll open an issue on StyleCI’s GitHub then :)

Comment: The use statement is redundant in this case, because the `Controller` class you're extending is already in the defined `App\Http\Controllers` namespace. I've seen this being marked with a notice by PHPStorm as well, although I can't see why it can't take into account the `use` statement as well.

Comment: In my experience the `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` statement is something that gets generated when using the `artisan make:controller` and I usually just remove it because it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `Controller` is in the same namespace as your `FooController` so StyleCI is trying to tell you your `use` statement is redundant.

Although it is still a bug as the warning from StyleCI should be more descriptive.

Comment: so `class FooController extends Controller` will work without the prior `use` statement, because they’re in the same relative namespace?